# Impression in German (Doch , Noch etc.)

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

How Can I use *doch, noch, na ja* and *gar* inside the sentences for showing  impressions correctly?

Comment: Please give an example of what you want to say. These words are very different in usage.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what information you're looking for that's not given by a dictionary. You might find *na ja* under *naja*.

Comment: Wir könnten doch heute Mittag zusammen in die Kantine gehen 
I have no Idea what would (DOCH) means in such cases ?

Comment: I would also maybe search for "Modalpartikel" on your preferred search engine. It's a broader topic, and for example *Easy German* on Youtube have some good videos about this.

Answer (score 1):

In the example given in the comments, *doch* is a modal adverb (also known as a modal particle, flavoring particle or *Modalpartikel*). In general, these tell you how the speaker "feels" about what's going on in the sentence. They are notoriously difficult to translate since what the speaker intends to convey by them can depend on context and tone of voice. In your example it may convey that this information is not new to the listener: "You know, we could go to the canteen together this afternoon." Both people know that going to the canteen is possible, and the speaker is just reminding the other person of that fact as a suggestion. With a different tone of voice it can also convey impatience, as if the fact is obvious and the listener is being obtuse: "Well, obviously we could go to the canteen together this afternoon." It could also be a way contradicting something the listener said: "There's nothing to do around here." "Yes there is, we could go to the canteen together this afternoon." There are other possible interpretations of *doch* as well, not to mention it's meaning as a conjunction. You should consult a dictionary for more information, but to really learn modal adverbs I think you have to look at lots of examples in context since what is meant by them is difficult to explain precisely.

The other expressions you listed in the original question are different parts of speech, not modal adverbs. I suggest creating separate questions for them with examples and more explanation of what you want to know about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I would say model adverbs are little bit confusing since it much depends on the personal impressions and have no precis translation.. anyway I would try dictionary as well .. thanks for your valuable efforts

Comment: @aws kareem: Modal adverbs are a favorite subject of German learning videos, so type "german modal adverbs" or "german modal particles" into YouTube for related material. But, as you said, much depends on personal impressions, and different videos may have different points of view on what given word might mean.